# pySpark: Put a Kafka stream into parquet and read parquet from remote session

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, apache-kafka, parquet

i have a bitnami spark docker infrastructure (one master and one worker).

Spark read Kafka stream.

```
stream_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka1:19091")\
    .option("subscribe", "Aleca")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()
```

Modify stream_df using select, filter .....

And write stream_df into parquet file.

```
   df_edge.writeStream\
        .format("parquet")\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/edge/check")\
        .option("path", "/tmp/edge/data")\
        .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')\
        .start()\
        .awaitTermination()
```

I send data using Kafka and when a check the the directory "/tmp/edge/data", i have only one directory _spark_metadata.

In this directory i have json file with snappy file path. But the snappy are not created.

From a different docker container, i try to read parquet file.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .appName('Flask_gunicorn') \
    .master('spark://0.0.0.0:7077') \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12') \
    .config('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '1g') \
    .config('spark.cores.max', '1') \
    .config('spark.jars.ivy', '/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy') \
    .config('spark.jars', '/opt/bitnami/spark/jars') \
    .getOrCreate()

edge_df = spark.read.csv(edge_location)
```

The read return an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/apao-flask-gunicorn/graph_generator.py", line 22, in <module>
    vertex_df = spark.read.parquet(edge_location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 353, in parquet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 134, in deco
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/tmp/edge/parquet;
```

If i try the read using spark shell:
I have an error file .....snappy.parquet doesn't exist.

But if a submit an app that read parquet file on spark container i have an access to data ....

I have try with csv file, i have similar error.

What is the way to have snappy file, when a put stream ?

Thanks
Sebastien

Comment: "From a different docker container"... Containers don't share volumes by default. Secondly, you're writing to /tmp/edge/data, not /tmp/edge/parquet

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I have made lot of tries and copy paste and i copy paste 2 different tries with incoherent path (path are not the root cause).   I have try to share volume but these volumes are created as root. My application haven't the right to put parquet files in created volumes. Is there a simple way to share not root volume ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can mount volumes as a different user, but mounts should be able to be written by any user. It would be useful if you could show your docker commands or compose file. In general, though, I'd suggest using a separate MinIO or HDFS container rather than reading/writing to local container filesystems

Comment: Hello one more time. I have mount a volume on spark master to share meta-data with my flask container. This part works and now flask can see the directory. But with this modification a lost parquets files in the worker .... i don't know why mount a volume on master break the worker ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you'd need to share data, but like I said, you should really be using a shared _networked_ filesystem such as the two options I listed... If you want the data to arrive back at the flask container, you'd need to use `collect()` in the Spark code and have it be the driver (which would cause unnecessary load for a webserver, so is overall not recommended)

Answer (score 1):

Last news

My infra:

Container Flask(no data) ->  Container Spark master(json metadata) ->  Container Spark worker (parquet files)

When a start my python script(with remote session on Spark master) on Flask container, the read of metadata is done locally on Flask container and not in Spark master.

If i call a spark-submit to master spark (with local session) from flask container, i have the same pb.

If i call a spark-submit to master spark (with local session) from master spark container, it is working fine, but i prefer having separate docker file.

Thanks to @OneCricketeer for explainations.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    name: aleca_network

services:
  spark:
    build: .
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    volumes:
      - ./master-ivy-jars:/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy:z
      #- ./vertex_data:/opt/bitnami/spark/data/vertex
      #- ./edge_data:/opt/bitnami/spark/data/edge

  spark-worker-1:
    build: .
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp
      - SPARK_WORKER_PORT=7078
    volumes:
      - ./worker1-ivy-jars:/opt/bitnami/spark/ivy:z
      #- ./vertex_data:/opt/bitnami/spark/data/vertex
      #- ./edge_data:/opt/bitnami/spark/data/edge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/spark:3-debian-10

USER root
RUN pip install numpy

USER 1001
RUN mkdir /tmp/vertex
RUN mkdir /tmp/vertex/data
RUN mkdir /tmp/vertex/check

RUN mkdir /tmp/edge
RUN mkdir /tmp/edge/data
RUN mkdir /tmp/edge/check


RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.0.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.6.2/commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/commons-pool2-2.6.2.jar
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.4.1/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/kafka-clients-2.4.1.jar
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.0.1/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.1.jar
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-tags_2.12/3.0.1/spark-tags_2.12-3.0.1.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/spark-tags_2.12-3.0.1.jar
```